# ruby - get files of certain extension from a directory (windows)

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble with the following piece of code where user input of directory name is used to fetch list of files of a particular extension on a `windows` machine

```
puts "Enter the name of directory where files exist : "
directory = gets.chomp
csv_files = Dir.glob("#{directory}/*.csv")
```

Regardless of the directory input ( the directory has .csv files), the last line returns an empty array.

ruby version - `ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]`

**Adding additional info asked in comments**

```
PS C:\test> irb
irb(main):001:0> directory = gets.chomp
C:\test
=> "C:\\test"
irb(main):002:0> directory
=> "C:\\test"
irb(main):003:0> Dir.glob("#{directory}/*.csv")
=> []

irb(main):004:0> Dir.glob("#{directory}/*.*")
=> []

irb(main):005:0> Dir.glob("C:/" + directory + "/*.csv")
=> []

irb(main):006:0> Dir.glob("C:/test/*")
=> ["C:/test/test_csv.csv"]

irb(main):007:0> Dir.entries(directory)
=> [".", "..","test_csv.csv"]

irb(main):010:0> Dir.glob('./*.csv')
=> ["./test_csv.csv"]
irb(main):011:0>
```

Comment: How your input directory looks like? If you change the glob pattern to Dir.glob("#{directory}/*.*") it returns something else?

Comment: input directory looks like `C:\test` with couple of files with `.csv` extension. Changing the pattern to `Dir.glob("#{directory}/*.*")` is giving an empty array.

Comment: Does `Dir.glob("C:/" + directory + "/*.csv")` work?

Comment: @user3206440: What happens if you hardcode the directory name? For example `Dir.glob("C:/mydir/*")`.

Comment: @user3206440: One more thing you could try: In your original program, write `Dir.entries(directory)`. This will return **really** all files in the directory, so you can verify that you are looking at the correct directory, and it will throw an exception, if the directory does not exist.

Comment: @user3206440 You can`t use backslashes with Dir.glob. Check the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html).

Comment: @user1934428 updated the question with additional info.

Comment: @user3206440: Well, as you can see: Your variable `directory` contains backslashes as separator. You know: Garbage in -> garbage out  ;-)

Comment: @user1934428 - the input is `C:\test` -> what transformation need to be done to this input to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution as below.

Use `File.expand_path` method to convert the input string into a standard ruby file path.

```
puts "Enter the name of directory where files exist : "
directory = File.expand_path(gets.chomp)
csv_files = Dir.glob("#{directory}/*.csv")
```

Comment: This solution has the side effect  to turn a relative path into an absolute one, which is not necessarily what you want to do. An alternative would be to simply replace backslashes by forward slashes (`gets.chomp.gsub('\\','/')`).